# How to avoid barbuttonitem to overlap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i've been trying to hide a bar button that keeps appearing under my "Menu" barbuttonitem

You can see under the "Menu" button it says "Atras" which was a button from the last viewcontroller

[image: BarButtonItemImageUpload]

Comment: Please share your code and relevant application layout. It is impossible to help you just by looking at the picture

Comment: No need to share code, because it's random, and hardly to recurrent. If it happens, you have to restart your app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check if the bar button item is not nil. If it is not, set it to nil first and then add the intended bar button item there.

In my case, I just disabled edge swiping in my `UINavigationController` to prevent this from happening.

`self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = false`